# Bounds for the rank of the sum of two linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The following is *Exercise 3.15* from the German textbook *Lineare Algebra* by Hans-*Joachim Kowalsky* and *Gerhard O. Michler*:

Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ two linear maps from a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ to a finite-dimensional vector space $W$ with $\dim{\varphi(V)} = m$ and $\dim{\psi(V)} = n$. Show that $$|m-n| \leq \operatorname{rk}(\varphi + \psi) \leq m + n.$$

**Progress and Approaches**:

- The second inequality can be shown by using the fact that the image of $\varphi + \psi$ is contained in the sum of the images of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ and the [dimension formula for subspaces](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-dimension-of-a-sum-of-subspaces).
- However, the other direction does not turn to work as smoothly. I tried to consider the kernels of $\varphi$, $\psi$ and $\varphi+\psi$ with the hope that I could apply the Rank-Nullity-Theorem and the dimension formula from before. But it turns out that there is no relationship between these.

I also do not know how to acquire the absolute value of $m-n$ in the end. This must mean that one needs to assume that one image is larger than the other. But I do not see how this is supposed to work.

Could you please help me with this exercise? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rk}{\operatorname{rk}} \newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$

Note that $\rk \varphi = \rk (- \varphi)$, since $\im \varphi = - \im \varphi$. Now, by the item that you have already solved,

$$
\rk \psi = \rk (\psi + \varphi -\varphi) \leq \rk(\psi+\varphi) + \rk (-\varphi) = \rk(\psi+\varphi) + \rk \varphi.
$$

and so $\rk \psi - \rk \varphi \leq \rk (\psi + \varphi)$. Interchanging the roles of $\psi$ and $\varphi$ we get that $\rk \varphi - \rk \psi \leq \rk \psi + \varphi$ and so

$$
|m-n| = |\rk \psi - \rk \varphi| \leq \rk (\psi + \varphi).
$$